# Is partaking of the Holy Eucharist the key to incorruptibility of the saints?

Tags: catholicism, communion, relics, incorruptibility

[*The Incorruptibles*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=5859) by Joan Caroll Cruz has many stories about incorruptible saints.

These saints with incorruptible bodies are Catholic, and I never heard any Protestant, other non-Catholic Christians, or even other religions claim they have members whose bodies are incorrupt. Does the Catholic Church have a good explanation on why this is?

Does the Holy Eucharist have something to do with the incorruptibility?

Comment: I would like to point out that the Orthodox (see "other non-Catholic Christians") claim several incorrupt, post-Schism saints; see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incorruptibility).

Answer (score 2):

**Inedia**, according to the Catholic theologian Antonio Royo Marín, O.P. ([*Teología de la Perfección Cristiana*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=4068) p. 845), is the "*ayuno absoluto durante un tiempo muy superior al que resisten las fuerzas naturales*" ["absolute fast lasting much longer than natural forces can endure"], in which only Holy Communion is received. He continues ([*ibid*.](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=4068) p. 846):

> Supuesta, finalmente, la sobrenaturalidad del fenómeno, habrá que explicarlo, desde el punto de vista teológico, por una especie de *incorruptibilidad anticipada de los cuerpos gloriosos*, que suspende la ley del incesante desgaste de los órganos y dispensa, por lo mismo, de la ley correlativa de la refección alimenticia.
>
> [Assuming the supernaturality of the phenomenon, it will have to be explained from the theological viewpoint, by a type of *anticipated incorruptibility of the glorified bodies*, which suspends the law of the incessant degradation of the organs and, therefore, dispenses from the correlative law of needing refreshment from food.]

One [effect of Holy Communion is attaining glory](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/TP/TP079.html#TPQ79A2THEP1) and everlasting life: "If any man eat of this bread, he shall live for ever" ([Jn. 6:52](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=50&ch=6&l=52-#x)). One can only receive Holy Communion worthily within the Catholic Church (cf. [St. Thomas on whether one can receive Communion from schismatic or heretical priests](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/TP/TP082.html#TPQ82A9THEP1)). Thus, it makes sense that the incorruptibles are Catholic.

A few examples of incorruptibles who experienced inedia (cf. [*Teología de la Perfección Cristiana*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=4068) p. 845):

- [St. Catherine of Siena](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=5930) (1347–1380), for ~8 years
- [Teresa Neumann](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7003) (1898-1962), from 1926-1962.

For more examples of incorruptibles who also experienced inedia, see [*The Incorruptibles*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=5859).